# apigee "Subject does not have permission" to get logged in user

Tags: apigee

Code that was previously working to get the logged in user is now failing.  For the default role I have a few permissions including this one (in the list at /roles/xxx/permissions):

```
"get:/users/me"
```

To verify I didn't break something in the API, I logged in from Curl (names modified to protect the guilty):

```
curl -X POST "https://api.usergrid.com/xxx/xxx/token" -d '{"grant_type":"password", "username":"test", "password":"xxx"}'
```

This gets a valid response with an access token:

```
{"access_token":"YWMxxxNnAHCEeSEEUF6k0-adAAAAUcaO_3R5IcK1ftFnDt0x52NVSoHEATWD6Q","expires_in":604800,"user":{"uuid":"a2517xxx-d3dc-11e3-b4fb-17caf255a670","type":"user","name":"Test User","created":1399243032076,"modified":1399243032076,"username":"test","email":"test@test.com","activated":true,"picture":"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b64xxx217b34b1e8d3bd915fc65c4452"}}
```

Using this access token, compose the Curl request to get /users/me:

```
curl -X GET https://api.usergrid.com/xxx/xxx/users/me?access_token=YWMxxxNnAHCEeSEEUF6k0-adAAAAUcaO_3R5IcK1ftFnDt0x52NVSoHEATWD6Q
```

Now instead of working as I believe it used to, I get this:

```
{"error":"unauthorized","timestamp":1404289792782,"duration":0,"exception":"org.apache.shiro.authz.UnauthorizedException","error_description":"Subject does not have permission [applications:get:d5e9e5a0-d310-11e3-a524-df009e0fbc2f:/users/a25174ca-d3dc-11e3-b4fb-17caf255a670]"}
```

Have I broken something and just missing it?  I tried deleting the permission and recreating it but that didn't help either.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you cannot use 'me' as the entity to retrieve self. You would need to specify the actually username or uuid of the user entity. Luckily when you retrieve a token, that info is passed back in the response, so you can save it.

See [getting a user](http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/user) in the Apigee docs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion remus, but on that page you linked it explains how to use "/users/me":
    User UUID, username, or email address. The alias /users/me can be used in place of the current user’s uuid, username, or email address. Note: The /users/me endpoint is accessible only if you provide an access token with the request (see Authenticating users and application clients). If you make an anonymous ("guest") call, the system will not be able to determine which user to return as /users/me.

Answer (score 0):

@remus question prompted me to find an example on the security page to show where I had gotten the permission from.  However, the page http://apigee.com/docs/app-services/content/managing-access-defining-permission-rules now shows this example:

```
GET,PUT,POST,DELETE:/users/me/**
```

I'm fairly certain that wasn't the case earlier as this code had been working for weeks with the prior permission.  Maybe I bumped my head :-) hopefully anyone else having this problem will find this.  The curl examples posted in the question now work fine with this permission set (although I only added GET permission in my case).